# Algo for covering maximum surface of a polygon with rectangles

Tags: algorithms, surfaces, polygons

I'm looking to an algorithm to covering maximum surface of a polygon with rectangles. Rectangles have to have a specific width, a rectangle can't overlap an other one and each one has to fit in the polygon. I've already looking for other posts but I couldn't find an algo without overlap or specific width.

Note: The length can be different for any rectangle and rectangles can point in different directions.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think your question is well-posed. Why not just take sufficiently long rectangles and stack them one on top of another until your polygon is covered? Perhaps you mean: Each rectangle must fit inside the polygon?

Comment: Thanks @JosephO'Rourke. Youre were right, I edited my question.

Comment: Still not clear. The rectangles all have the same, given, width, but the lengths can be different and arbitrary? Must the rectangles all be aligned, or can they all point in different directions? Anyway, this is a *packing* problem, and maybe that keyword will aid your search. But optimal packing algorithms are few and far between, you may have to settle for considerably less than the maximum area, or for a really slow algorithm. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27055/what-is-an-efficient-packing-algorithm-for-packing-rectangles-into-a-polygon might be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303689/efficient-packing-algorithm-for-irregular-polygons might also be helpful.

Comment: The length can be different for any rectangle and rectangles can point in different directions. I'll try searching with this keyword. Thanks @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 4):

If the rectangles must be aligned (Gerry Myerson's question), then perhaps
this approximation might suffice, depending on your needs.
Let the width $w$ of your rectangles be $1$.
Orient your polygon $P$ randomly. Lay a series of unit-separated parallel lines
over $P$ and compute the area of the induced rectangle cover determined by
those lines.

---

[image: RectCover]

---

Reorient and repeat. Retain the maximal area.

It seems possible that the optimal orientation could be computed,
but at the moment I don't see how.

Comment: Unfortunately rectangles can point in different directions..

Comment: It may be that your problem is such a specific variant of rectangle packing that it has not yet been investigated. There has been work on packing with rectangles whose width is maximized; but the rectangles have different widths, just none very thin.